# OpenGL Light doesn't show up in my program

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to make a simple OpenGL Program with a sun shining. Here is my code so far:

```
void init() {
    glClearColor (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);

    // Lighting set up
    glLightModeli(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_LOCAL_VIEWER, GL_TRUE);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

    // Set lighting intensity and color
    GLfloat qaAmbientLight[]    = {0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0};
    GLfloat qaDiffuseLight[]    = {0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0};
    GLfloat qaSpecularLight[]   = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, qaAmbientLight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, qaDiffuseLight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, qaSpecularLight);

    // Set the light position
    GLfloat qaLightPosition[]   = {0, 0.758, 0.0, 1.0};
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, qaLightPosition);
}

void drawSun() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    // Set material properties
    GLfloat Yellow[] = {1.0, 0.647, 0.0, 1.0};
    GLfloat White[] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, Yellow);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, Yellow);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, White);
    glMaterialf(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, 60.0);

    float x, y;
    float radius = 0.095f;
    float x_mid = 0;
    float y_mid = 0.758;

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        x = x_mid + (float)radius * cos(359 * PI / 180.0f);
        y = y_mid + (float)radius * sin(359 * PI / 180.0f);
        for (int j = 0; j < 360; j++)
        {
            glVertex2f(x, y);
            x = x_mid + (float)radius * cos(j * PI / 180.0f);
            y = y_mid + (float)radius * sin(j * PI / 180.0f);
            glVertex2f(x, y);
        }
    glEnd();
}
```

But the sun doesn't shine, it looks like this :

[image]

I want to know if I make some mistakes in my code, any helps will be appreciated.

Comment: Just trying to gauge what you would like to have... are you looking for an effect like this: https://www.google.de/search?q=sun+shine&num=100&tbm=isch ?

Comment: @skalarproduktraum It's nice to have that, but my goal is only to make the sun emitting a light. So when the sun is set, the window will be dark.

Comment: You do not supply any normals, so your lighting cannot possibly work. Apart from that, I really recommend that you do not use this horribly outdated fixed-function stuff. It is 2017 after all, not 1997.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you call [`glColorMaterial`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColorMaterial.xml) to enable `GL_SPECULAR` that is off by default?

Also you are completely skipping all the error checking.

Comment: I have add it in the init( ), but the result still same

Comment: You probably need `glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)` as well.